# Where is the private forum for the Universal App Quick Start Program / Developer Transition Kit (DTK)?

Tags: apple-id, development, developer-program, apple-silicon

I've signed up and been accepted to the [Universal App Quick Start Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/universal/) and received my Apple Silicon Developer Transition Kit.

One of the featured benefits included in the program is access to a private forum:

[image]

> Private Forums
>
> Ask questions and connect with Apple engineers and other members of the Universal App Quick Start Program.

However, upon receiving my DTK, I cannot seem to find these "Private Forums" anywhere.

The new Apple Developer Forums are arranged under "tags": https://developer.apple.com/support/forums-tags/

But there is no tag listed for the Developer Transition Kit or Universal App Quick Start Program. The closest tag I can find is ["Universal Apps"](https://developer.apple.com/forums/tags/universal-apps/) for Apple Silicon.

Where is the private forum for the Universal App Quick Start Program?

---

This seems to be a common source of confusion:

- [Where is the private DTK forum?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Apple ID that **has been accepted** to the Universal App Quick Start Program, access the [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/).

Click your profile icon at the top right of the screen:

---

[image: link in forum profile]

---

You should see a link to the private forum:

> Developer Forums
> Universal App Quick Start

Which links to the forum/tag for the UAQSP/DTK, located here:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/tags/universal-app-quick-start

> Universal App Quick Start
> Private forums for program members

---

Notably, this `Universal App Quick Start` tag is *not* included in the list of [all forum tags](https://developer.apple.com/support/forums-tags/). So it's rather hard to find.